# Laravel: Having trouble handling multiple files for upload

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have an image uploader that allows multiple images on the frontend (vue.js).  When I send it over to Laravel, it's not hitting my `foreach` loop. I traced the `print` logs to be executing up until the `foreach` loops runs but I'm not sure why it's not going through each one unless that's not the correct way.

** JS **

```
let formData = new FormData();
this.files.forEach((x,index) => {
    formData.append("file", x)
});

axios.post('/admin/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
})
```

**Laravel **

```
print "outside";
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    print "inside";
    $files = $request->file('file');
    $stack = [];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        print "Looping";
        $fileName = Storage::put('/trace/', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()), ['visibility' => 'public']);
        array_push($stack, $fileName);
    }
    return response()->json($stack);
}
```

Comment: dd the $files variable, and check if you are sending the files to the server.

Answer (score 1):

As you are uploading multiple files the `file` formdata key should actually be an array like this - `formData.append("file[]", x)`